# How to process data javascript with php?

Tags: php, preg-match

I have crawl data from 1 site and I get the following string:

```
var image_data11723 = [ { "type_code":  "", "image_data": [ "graphics\/00000001\/COA389-l\u005F3\u005F350x280.jpg", "graphics\/00000001\/COA389-l\u005F3\u005F65x52.jpg", "graphics\/00000001\/COA389-l\u005F3.jpg" ] } ,{ "type_code": "", "image_data": [ "graphics\/00000001\/COA389-Dinette 1\u005F350x280.jpg", "graphics\/00000001\/COA389-Dinette 1\u005F65x52.jpg", "graphics\/00000001\/COA389-Dinette 1.jpg" ] } ,{ "type_code":  "", "image_data": [ "graphics\/00000001\/COA389-Poker Table 1\u005F350x280.jpg", "graphics\/00000001\/COA389-Poker Table 1\u005F65x52.jpg", "graphics\/00000001\/COA389-Poker Table 1.jpg" ] } ,{ "type_code":  "", "image_data": [ "graphics\/00000001\/COA389-Pool Table 1\u005F350x280.jpg", "graphics\/00000001\/COA389-Pool Table 1\u005F65x52.jpg", "graphics\/00000001\/COA389-Pool Table 1.jpg" ] } ,{ "type_code": "", "image_data": [ "graphics\/00000001\/COA389-Table CLoseup\u005F350x280.jpg", "graphics\/00000001\/COA389-Table CLoseup\u005F65x52.jpg", "graphics\/00000001\/COA389-Table CLoseup.jpg" ] } ,{ "type_code":  "", "image_data": [ "graphics\/00000001\/COA389-Chair 1\u005F350x280.jpg", "graphics\/00000001\/COA389-Chair 1\u005F65x52.jpg", "graphics\/00000001\/COA389-Chair 1.jpg" ] } ] var im11723 = new ImageMachine( 'COA389', 0, 'main\u005Fimage', 'thumbnails', 'closeup\u005Fdiv', 'closeup\u005Fimage', 'closeup\u005Fclose', '', 'B', 350, 360, 1, 'N', 900, 675, 1, 65, 65, 1, 'graphics\/00000001\/COA389.1-i.jpg' ); im11723.oninitialize( image_data11723 );
```

I want to get an array from the `image_data` variable, but I do not know how to accomplish this.

Comment: Response is in JSON format you can use json_decode to obtain array , which you want.

Comment: You got data from crawler with Js?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service, please show your code/effort and what the actual problem is.

Comment: I write code  preg_match_all('/([^\]]+)/', $str, $match); But it incorret

Comment: I can see your var is using with javascript and you try get by PHP? Right?

Comment: Yes, i want it return like picture http://prnt.sc/bvly5e. But it preg_match incorret. Cám ơn Quỳnh Nguyễn

Comment: Okay wait a moment

Answer (score 0):

The first you build `javascript` like this

```
data = JSON.stringify(image_data11723);
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "jsOnChange.php",
    // The key needs to match your method's input parameter (case-sensitive).
    data: data,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    async: false,
    error: function(e)
    {       
        alert(JSON.stringify(e, null, 4));                         
    },
    success: function(strDrivers){
        alert(JSON.stringify(strDrivers, null, 4));
    }
});
```

In jsOnChange.php = `listener` your var

```
<?php 
ini_set("allow_url_fopen", true);

$jsonStr = file_get_contents("php://input"); //read the HTTP body.
$json = json_decode($jsonStr, true);
$result_array = array();
foreach ($json as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($value['image_data'] as $key_2 => $value_2) {
        $result_array[0][] = $value_2;
    }
}
print_r($result_array);
?>
```

You will get this with `Firebug` Addon on Firefox. Or you can see with `Chrome`

[image]

Comment: Thank Quynh Nguyen, I have try preg_match_all and it correct. :D I got very data. Because i will use it. http://prntscr.com/bvm9im

Comment: Yes
preg_match_all('/"graphics((?!(\.jpg)).)*\.jpg"/', $str, $matchs);
$dataImage = json_decode('['.implode(",", $matchs[0]).']');

Comment: @AlexMato Btw, Are you Vietnamese? xD

Comment: Yes, nice to meet u. ^^

Comment: @AlexMato Nice to meet u too xD.